# Как правильно - "Ты нетворческий человек" или "Ты не творческий человек"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "Ты нетворческий человек" или "Ты не творческий человек"? Мне кажется, что надо писать раздельно — "не творческий", потому что это относительное прилагательное. Мне говорят, что качественное. Так какое прилагательное "творческий"?

Answer (score 2):

Тут дело не только в орфографии, это может быть **характеристика разных людей.**

**(1) Ты нетворческий человек.**

Обычно слитное написание связывают с возможностью замены слова **синонимами без НЕ.** И вот нетворческому человеку часто приписывают целый ряд **сопутствующих негативных качеств:** косный, консервативный, ограниченный,  примитивный, бесцветный, лишенный оригинальности и индивидуальности, бесталанный и пр.

Поэтому такую формулировку (нетворческий человек) следует использовать осторожно.

**(2) Ты не творческий человек.**

Хотя творческие способности у человека могут отсутствовать, но он  может обладать другими положительными качествами и  занимать в жизни достойное место. В конце концов, не всем же быть гениями, творцами  и созидателями нового.

Используя вариант с раздельным написанием, мы говорим только об отсутствии способностей к творчеству.

Примеры: Это был ум **острый и восприимчивый, но не творческий.** [Георгий Флоровский. Пути русского богословия (1936)]

**Я не творческий человек:** я умею собрать кусочки с разных сторон, их скомбинировать, но я ничего никогда не умел нового ни сказать, ни подумать. [митрополит Антоний  (1978)]

По профессии он был художник, но **не творческий, а прикладной**: рисовал обложки и иллюстрации для книг. [Алексей Слаповский.  2009][

Садкович ― щупленький, юркий, бесцветный, наглый, самодовольный, **совсем нетворческий,** неинтеллигентный, попал на режиссерский факультет по комсомольской путевке, . [Татьяна Окуневская. (1998)]

*Творческий процесс*: имеющий отношение к творчеству, **относительное** прилагательное.

*Творческий или нетворческий человек*: **качественное** прилагательное.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ответ исчерпывающий.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, можно сказать и так и так. При слитном написании утверждается отсутствие творческой жилки у человека, а при раздельном — отрицается её существование.

Если есть продолжение, правильно будет написать раздельно: *Ты не творческий человек, **а**... (такой и такой).*

Не силён в классификации прилагательных, но мне кажется, что это прилагательное качественное, как Вам другие говорят, потому что оно и характеризует качество человека.

Comment: Спасибо! Кое-что прояснилось.